# Can you move a commit back up the tree/in time with git?

Tags: git

Is it possible to move the changes in a commit to before other changes on the tree so I can test those commits.

In this example I want to move 'Romoved sess_match_useragent' to before 'Updated core to 2.1.0' in the tree

[image: mytree]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with `git rebase -i refspec`.

Here, `refspec` will be the identifier (either a SHA1 or a relative refspec) of the commit preceding your "Updated core" commit. This will open an editor with the commits and their order: move the `pick` line for your commit right before the "Updated core" one and quit the editor: git will rewrite the branch.

Note that you may have to solve conflicts, however.

Read the help in the editor along with the list of commits, too: it contains a lot of useful tips, you can do plenty. For instance, just `reword` commit messages if you have made spelling mistakes...

In your case, as pointed out, `refspec` can he `HEAD~17`, ie "17 commits before ref HEAD" (HEAD is always the tip of the branch you are currently on).

Comment: You can also use `HEAD~17` to mean 17 commits before `HEAD` (or `staging~17`).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate branch and then `cherry-pick` the changes you want to test.

```
git checkout -b feature/foo [sha of "Updated core to 2.1.0"]
git cherry-pick [sha of "Removed sess_match_useragent"]
```

This will not affected the existing history. However, usually you create a separate branch for every feature/bug you want to develop/fix and test separat from each other and then you only work with this branch, until you are happy with it. Then merge it back into `develop`, or `master`